# SQLAlchemy filter by date returns none even if the date exists

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a Python code for my class I'm trying to check if something is already in the SQL database because it is a unique condition. Python has been one of the most frustrating programming languages I've ever worked with and I just don't understand why this is not working. I'm assuming that too much of the logic is abstracted away (a common theme of python) which is causing thing to break that shouldn't break

I've only tried what my code is now, haven't figured out what to modify.

```py
@app.route("/newEvent/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def new_event():
    if "username" not in session:
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    if session["status"] != "user":
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    if request.method == "POST":
        event_on_date = Event.query.filter_by(date=datetime.strptime(request.form["date"], "%Y-%m-%d")).first()
        if event_on_date is not None:
            flash("event creation failed, event already exists on date")
            return redirect(url_for(home))
        uid = User.query.filter_by(username=session["username"]).first()
        uid = uid.id
        db.session.add(Event(uid, request.form["name"],
                             datetime.strptime(request.form["date"], "%Y-%m-%d")))
        db.session.commit()
        flash("event created")
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    else:
        return render_template("newEvent.html")
```

If I enter a repeat date, I get this:

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: event.date
[SQL: INSERT INTO event (requester_id, name, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (2, 'bhgiujhghjyg', '2019-01-01')]

I assumed that since the value being entered to the database is checked against before it is entered, it would catch it before it happens, however, the filter_By query for date simply returns None every time

```
        event_on_date = Event.query.filter_by(date=datetime.strptime(request.form["date"], "%Y-%m-%d")).first()
        if event_on_date is not None:
```

Comment: can you put up your model ?

Comment: Have you printed the value of `datetime.strptime(request.form["date"], "%Y-%m-%d")` to check that the date is being parsed correctly before you use it in the query filter?